# Installed Ruby, but getting "No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rvm

I have a mac running Mavericks where `$ rvm install 2.0.0` returns

```
Already installed ruby-2.0.0-p247.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall 2.0.0
```

but `$ ruby ~v` returns

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- ~v (LoadError)
```

I have Homebrew, Xcode 5.0.1, libtool,libxslt, libksba, openssl, and libyaml all installed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `ruby --version`, `ruby ~v` tries to load a file called `~v` which fails.

This is what happens for me:

```
$ ruby ~v
ruby: No such file or directory -- ~v (LoadError)

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.1]
```

To check your `rvm` ruby version, run `rvm list` and select one with `rvm use 2.0.0` and so on.

Comment: why does ruby ~v seem to work for some people online, but not me?

Comment: There's a shorter version of that version command, which would be what they're using: `ruby -v` is the same as `ruby --version`.